# In Mongoose I have User and Role schemas that have a one to many relationship. How to query if a particular User has the 'admin' role?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, one-to-many, mongoose-populate

I have two collections in my Mongo DB: users and roles.  A user can have many roles.  Using Mongoose I want to find out whether a particular user (based on their id) has the admin role.  How do I perform that query? In SQL one way of finding out would be to write this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Roles ON Users.id = Roles.userID
WHERE (Users.id = <some user id> AND Roles.name='admin')
```

But I'm failing to see how the equivalent query is done using Mongoose.  Below are my Mongoose schemas:

```
let RoleSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    owner: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
})
export let Role = mongoose.model("Role", RoleSchema)


let userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    roles: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Role"
        }
    ]
})
export let User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

```
User.
  findById(id). // can also use find/findOne depending on your use-case
  populate({
    path: 'roles',
    match: { name: 'admin' }
  }).
  exec();
```

This will fetch you User details and roles where `name` is `admin`.

You can check the `user.roles` array count to get the user is having admin role or not.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer and accompanying cite look promising  I'll run the code tomorrow and if it works I'll mark yours as the right answer. As an aside, I wish Mongoose doc writers could make a better index -- one that would channel the user toward those pages were one to search on "querying one to many relationships."  The saving grace of course is stackoverflow which increasingly seems to be the index via which one finds the appropriate docs. Again, thanks for your answer!